# Regular Expression to Match All Occurrences Before Specified Character

Tags: regex

I want to find all occurrences of `.` in a string that occur before a `=`. The string that I am performing the search on is:

```
case pencil.tip.crop.circle.badge.plus = "pencil.tip.crop.circle.badge.plus"
```

I am using the following regular expression to target everything that occurs before the `=`:

```
.+?(?==)
```

Below, you can see the results of the search:

[image: Screenshot of highlighted results of regular expression search on string]

The highlighted result is from where I would like to extract all occurrences of `.` in order to obtain all occurrences of `.` that occur before the `=`.

I assume that I need to escape `.` in my expression, but I do not know where I need to do that in order to extract all occurrences. I understand that `.+?` matches all characters, but replacing `.+?` with `\.+?` yields no results:

[image: Screenshot of highlighted results of regular expression search on string]

What expression do I need in order to obtain all occurrences of `.` that occur before the `=`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
\.(?=.*=)
```

- `\.` Match a literal `.`
- `(?=.*=)` Lookahead to match zero or more characters followed by a `=`.

[image]

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/yq7zUB/1).

Answer (score 1):

`.+?(?==)` - matches one or more non-linebreak characters as few as possible, that are are followed with `=`. It happens because the dot is not escaped, and the `(?==)` lookahead looks immediately to the right.

I am afraid `\.(?=.*=)` [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63873229/11329890) may overmatch if a `=` character appears in the double quoted value.

There are at least two more precise alternatives:

```
\G[^\r\n.=]*\K\.
```

See [proof (PCRE)](https://regex101.com/r/D6lFq0/1). Matches zero or more characters other than linebreaks, dots and equal signs, dropped later with `\K`, and `\.` matches literal dots.

Also, consider

```
(?<=^[^\r\n=]*?)\.
```

See [proof (JS)](https://regex101.com/r/D6lFq0/2). Matches any dot that has zero or more characters other than linebreaks and equal signs, as few as possible, at the start of string before the dots.